# Scott Addict R2 2008 crankset replacement

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket

I want to replace crankset on my Scott Addict R2 2008. Current crankset is Dura Ace 7800. If I looked correctly then currently I am using BB SM-BB71-41. New crankset will use BB386EVO.

Which BB do I need for this crankset? Probably BB for Pressfit BB386EVO?

Are there any other limitations (frame, ...)? Which BB is compatible with this frame and crankset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your frame uses BB86, so you'll need a BB86 bottom bracket for BB386evo cranks: https://www.bike24.com/p2114179.html